# android Web view Swipe To refresh in website navigation bar Scrolling Down issue

Tags: android, webview

[navigation open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYX2Y.png)I build android app that open different website  in web view but when i am open Walmart website i face problem on website navigation bar when i scroll down my website navigation bar  not going on top it's perfrom swipe to refresh.
[Scroll for going on top of navigation top but not scroll going swipe to refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em9pK.png)

my xml file is:--

```
`<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_height= "match_parent">


    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>`
```

My java code is :--

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView myWebView;
Context context;
Toolbar toolbar;
ProgressBar progressBar;
SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
WebSettings settings;

RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClientDemo());
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.walmart.com/");
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
            new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    myWebView.reload();
                }
            }
    );

    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

sorry for bad English
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: You have to see the scroll position, if it is completely swiped down, ie when y position is zero do refresh.

Step 2: You can do it by using [canChileScrollUp()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#canChildScrollUp()) method

This is a custom refreshlayout which has a function "canChildScrollUp" detects weather to refresh or not, if it returns false it will not refresh.

"canSwipeRefreshChildScrollUp" is place where u will write your logic in activity. in ur case use custom webview and detect the scroll position and if the scroll is completely done then only return true

```
public class CustomSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

private CanChildScrollUpCallback mCanChildScrollUpCallback;

public interface CanChildScrollUpCallback {
    boolean canSwipeRefreshChildScrollUp();
}

public void setCanChildScrollUpCallback(CanChildScrollUpCallback canChildScrollUpCallback) {
    mCanChildScrollUpCallback = canChildScrollUpCallback;
}

@Override
public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
    if (mCanChildScrollUpCallback != null) {
        return mCanChildScrollUpCallback.canSwipeRefreshChildScrollUp();
    }
    return super.canChildScrollUp();
}
}
```

In your Activity

```
public class YourActivity implements CustomSwipeRefreshLayout.CanChildScrollUpCallback {

private CustomSwipeRefreshLayout mRefreshLayout;
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // after initialization
    mRefreshLayout.setCanChildScrollUpCallback(this);
}

@Override
public boolean canSwipeRefreshChildScrollUp() {
    return mWebview.getScrollY() > 0;
}
}
```

TO detect nested  scroll you can use this

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView{
@Override
protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
    if(clampedX || clampedY){
        //Content is not scrolling
        //TODO Enable SwipeRefreshLayout
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
         //TODO Disable SwipeRefreshLayout
    }
}
}
```